Scrolldown and visibility
public static boolean scrollUntilVisible(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, int maxScrollAttempts) {
        int scrollAttempts = 0;
        int scrollIncrement = 100; // Her kaydırma işlemi için kullanılacak artış miktarı
        int targetY = element.getLocation().getY(); // Öğenin y dikey koordinatı

        while (scrollAttempts < maxScrollAttempts) {
            if (element.isDisplayed()) {
                return true; // Öğe görünürse true döndür
            }
            // Sayfayı aşağı kaydır
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, " + scrollIncrement + ");");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500); // Bekleme süresi
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            scrollAttempts++;
        }
        return false; // Belirli deneme sayısına ulaşıldığında false döndür
    }



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
